# Verify authenticity of a digital ticket

Tags: security

Let's say there's an app for a fair. This fair has a bunch of vendors.
The user sees the store catalog for each vendor and make purchases directly from the app.

All he has to do is come and pick up the item from the specified vendor.

For security reasons, the app needs to get confirmation from both sides: buyer and seller.

The buyer has to confirm he **got the item** and the seller has to have confirmation the item was successfully **paid for**.

How can you make it work without adding too much friction to the process? 
Considering the vendor will probably have a heavy flow of customers coming through and not all of them use the app (they use physical tickets), I believe requiring the vendor to have a system of his own to cross information in order to have confirmation would be difficult. (for instance, QR code readers would do the trick, but would require the vendor to have two sets of workflows and would therefore hamper his performance)

**So the question is:** is there a way to verify a "digital ticket" authenticity without cross referencing it to a second system, but only through a human?

Comment: What does the vendor do with the normal tickets? Is it like a fair where 300 tickets = 1 thing, or are they orders to where 1 order = 1 ticket?

Comment: Each type of ticket has a value of it's own: 1 blue ticket for a sandwich, 1 green ticket for a soda, etc.

Comment: Could you not read qr on physical and digital tickets?

Answer (score 1):

I may be thinking too much like an engineer here, but (very high level) if you could provide the vendors a randomized list of ticket numbers, ie tckt-9308083, tck-3709883, etc, when a user buys an item he would approach the vendor, display the ticket number, and the vendor would just plug in that number in their vendor app as it would automatically cross reference with their existing tickets, which would then prove to the vendor that this person's ticket is in fact valid.

This is similar to the system in fast food places where you pay for an item, receive a receipt with an order number, then give it to the server to prove its your order when picking it up.

Does that make sense or should I clarify a bit more?

Comment: It does, it makes a lot of sense. But I think it still leaves out the issue with the vendor having to reference the number with another system, which differs from his normal workflow, that is trusting the paper ticket from the buyer without having to check if it's valid. I'm looking for a way for the process to be closer to a regular transaction: user buys ticket, user gives ticket do vendor in exchange for the item.

Comment: @JotaRMonteiro could you have a confirmation code be sent to the vendor when the user clicks "redeem tickets"? That way any vendor can just check their phone and know that the guy in front of them is the buyer, it wouldn't differ that much from the normal work flow since they're already quite used to using services like Stripe and Square. I know its not exactly what you asked for, but its a tough problem, I'll admit.

Comment: That solution works just fine, with the user opting to redeem the ticket and the vendor instantly receiving a notification and checking the number he got with the number on the users screen. I still want to stress this problem with the vendor having to cross reference it with a second system, mainly because even if they already use similar services, they show a lot of resistance adopting a second set of tools and workflows.